# EF Navigation - map property to multiple tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mapping

I have a column in a table that is a foreign key to either of two tables and another column that saves which table

```
NoteID    NavigationType    NavigationTypeID
   1        Order               1234
   2        Person              555
```

I need to map the `NavigationTypeID` to either the `Order` table or the `Person` table.

```
public int NoteID { get; set; }
public string NavigationType { get; set; }
public int NavigationTypeID { get; set; }
public virtual Order order{get;set;}
public virtual Person person {get;set;}
```

I am using `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration` for mapping entities

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Quote)
.WithOne(t => t.Note)
 .HasForeignKey(d => d.NavigationTypeID);
```

Is there a way to set up my entity framework mapping to load this navigation based on the `NavigationType`?

Comment: Relational database doesn't help you doing that. So because EF is designed for Relational Database you can't do that kind of thing.

Comment: Is it more proper to have a column for each type and set the relationship?

Comment: Foreign Key belong to only one table not more.

Comment: Got it, Oh well. Would've been neat to do it this way.

Comment: [I will revert to my former statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497057/entity-framework-many-to-many-with-shared-foreign-key#comment68240162_40497057)

Comment: Thanks for the term polymorpic